# Change in radiobutton is not being registered

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, radio-button

I have a navigation activity consisting of fragments. The app is, currently, made to take the selected Id from the radiogroup and display it's text as a toast on a click of a button. But the app only display's the radiobutton that is already checked (Defined in xml), if I change the radiobutton that is selected, it will still show the one that was checked as defined in the xml

This is the java class (FirstFragment.java)

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

View myView;

private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioButton;
Button btnDisplay;
String text;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);


    btnDisplay = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(this);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) myView.findViewById(R.id.radio);
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) myView.findViewById(selectedId);

    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            text = radioButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

And this is the xml file

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="89dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioGram"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="Gram"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioKilogram"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kilogram"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:checked="true"/>

    </RadioGroup>
```

So, in this case, the toast would show "Kilogram", but if I check the "Gram" radiobutton, the toast would still show "Kilogram". Could anyone help fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
private RadioButton rb_1, rb_2;


 //in on createView
    rb_1 = (RadioButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.radioGram);
    rb_2 = (RadioButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.radioKilogram);

     rb_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            rb1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        rb_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            rb2.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Alternative way: write this in onCreateView() after you have initilized myView

```
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) myView.findViewById(R.id.radio);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
         switch(checkedId){
                case R.id.radioGram:
                    // do operations specific to this selection
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Gram selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.radioKilogram:
                    // do operations specific to this selection
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"KiloGram selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }  
    }
});
```

Comment: Both those segments of code crash the app, and I figured one thing out, and it's that lines like "RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup); " or "rb_1 = (RadioButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.radioGram);" crash the app when the button is clicked

Comment: Anything else I could try?

Comment: @Taha check the edited alternative way answer...also make sure your layout id and radiobuttons id are correct..

Comment: Of course I made sure the id's are correct. As for the new edit, I get an error on OnCheckedChangeListener saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'OnCheckedChangeListener'", and a error from (At sign)Override saying "Method does not method from its superclass"

Comment: try import this: import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) myView.findViewById(selectedId);
```

inside onCreateView which is calling only once. Because of that every time same value getting displayed on toast. Try to get value inside onClick:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

View myView;

private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioButton;
Button btnDisplay;
String text;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);


    btnDisplay = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(this);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) myView.findViewById(R.id.radio);
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) myView.findViewById(selectedId);

    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) myView.findViewById(selectedId);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            text = radioButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: This did not work, the same issue persisted, anything else I could try?